# creating a username that is an emailaddress

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a login for my site. Below shows the registration page. The emailaddress is their username. How do create an error message alert if an @ symbol and . has not been inserted into the username(emailaddress) field?

```
<?php

// Check if he wants to register:
if (!empty($_POST[emailaddress]))
{
    // Check if passwords match.
    if ($_POST[password] != $_POST[password2])
        exit("Error - Passwords don't match. Please go back and try again.");

    // Assign some variables.
    $date = mktime("d - m - Y");
    $ip = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];

    require_once("config.php");

    // Register him.
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO neworders 
    (emailaddress, firstname, surname, password, datereg, ip)
    VALUES  ('$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[surname]','$_POST[password]','$datereg','$ip')")
    or die ("Error - Couldn't register user.");

    echo "Welcome $_POST[username]! You've been successfully reigstered!<br /><br />
        Please login <a href='login.php'><b>here</b></a>.";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Holy vulnerabilities, Batman! Sanitize your data!

Comment: ..and increase your accept rating!!

Comment: i wonder what the content of `$date = mktime("d - m - Y");` will be :-) ...my guess 3600 ( or 1970-01-01 01:00:00 )

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a more robust solution to validate emails. Use PHP's `filter_var()` function with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag.

```
$validEmail = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Of course, this is just for validating the email. If you're inserting it into a database, use that database's escape mechanism for strings or use bound queries.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think it's possible to write an injection attack in a valid email address. Email addresses are pretty flexible before the `@` symbol haha. Should probably use mysql_real_escape_string on all inputs as well.

Comment: I wouldn't call that robust, but that's good for a quick solution.  It's not 100% secure though.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. To validate an email, I'd use this. To insert it into a database, I'd use the database's escape mechanism.

Comment: @Nilpo What's not *secure* about an email address?

Comment: @Paul the newline injection ? this should be fixed years ago.

Comment: @alex There's a big difference between data validation and sanitization.  A valid email address still has the potential to contain injection attacks.  My point was that this doesn't actually add any security to the application.

Comment: @Nilpo Injection attacks where? If my program says "that email is valid", where is the problem? I think you're making the (incorrect) assumption that I advocated using this technique to make the string safe in SQL.

Comment: @alex What will make the discussion clear is for you to quit being pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function at the bottom of this page:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585

Comment: Pretty funny... I was just writing a comment that linked to the same page.  
I guess Google worked for you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string has characters in it with the stristr() php function (This is not the ideal solution, but just very simply checks if characters in a string exist like you described.  Using filter_var as described below is a better solution).
So to do what you are asking you could do something like:

```
if(!(stristr($_POST['emailaddress'], '@') && stristr($_POST['emailaddress'], '.')) {
  echo 'Email not valid';
  exit(1);
}
```

Something else you could do is use the prebuilt php filter_var function to do this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```
if(!filter_var($_POST['emailaddress'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo 'Email not valid';
  exit(1);
}
```

You can also use regex pattern matching if you want.  I would also advise to do some sort of cleaning (mysql_real_string_escape) on the $_POST['emailaddress'] field, if you are inserting it into a database.